# What “Attribute node cannot follow non-attribute node in element content” tells me

Tags: xquery, xslt-2.0

> `one-attr.xml`

```
<requestConfirmation xmlns="http://example/confirmation">
    <trade>
        <amount>
            <currency id="settlementCurrency">USD</currency>
            <referenceAmount>StandardISDA</referenceAmount>
            <cashSettlement>true</cashSettlement>
        </amount>
    </trade>
</requestConfirmation>
```

> `two-attr.xml`

```
<requestConfirmation xmlns="http://example/confirmation">
    <trade>
        <cal>
          <c>PRECEDING</c>
            <bcs id="businessCenters">
              <bc>USNY</bc>
              <bc>GBLO</bc>
            </bcs>
        </cal>  
        <amount>
            <currency id="settlementCurrency" currencyScheme="http://example/iso4">USD</currency>
            <referenceAmount>StandardISDA</referenceAmount>
            <cashSettlement>true</cashSettlement>
        </amount>
    </trade>
</requestConfirmation>
```

> I use XQuery to transform the `id` attribute into element. There are only two documents like `two-attr.xml` out of 70K documents.
> Apparently, the `currency` element already has value `USD`. I got below error in the ML QConsole when transforming `two-attr.xml`. I got very similar error in Oxygen.

```
XDMP-ATTRSEQ: (err:XQTY0024) $node/@*[fn:local-name(.) = $attr] -- Attribute node cannot follow non-attribute node in element content
```

> My XQuery module:

```
declare namespace hof = "http://fc.fasset/function";
declare function hof:remove-attr-except
  ( $node as node()* ,
    $newNs as xs:string ,
    $keepAttr as xs:string* 
  ) as node()* 
  {
    for $attr in $node/@*
    return 
    if (local-name($attr) = $keepAttr)
    then (element {fn:QName ($newNs, name($attr))} {data($attr)})
    else
      $node/@*[name() = $keepAttr], hof:transform-ns-root-flatten($node/node(), $newNs, $keepAttr)
  };
declare function hof:transform-ns-root-flatten
  ( $nodes as node()* ,
    $newNs as xs:string ,
    $keepAttr as xs:string*
  ) as node()* 
  {
    for $node in $nodes
    return 
        typeswitch($node)
            case $node as element()
                return (element { fn:QName ($newNs, local-name($node)) }
                            { hof:remove-attr-except($node, $newNs, $keepAttr) }
                       )
            case $node as document-node()
                return hof:transform-ns-root-flatten($node/node(), $newNs, fn:normalize-space($keepAttr))          
    default return $node 
  };
(:  let $inXML := doc("/fasset/bug/two-attr.xml") :)
let $inXML := 
let $inXML := 
<requestConfirmation xmlns="http://example/confirmation">
    <trade>
      <cal>
         <c>PRECEDING</c>
            <bcs id="businessCenters">
              <bc>USNY</bc>
              <bc>GBLO</bc>
            </bcs>
        </cal>  
        <amount>
            <currency id="settlementCurrency" currencyScheme="http://example/iso4">USD</currency>
            <referenceAmount>StandardISDA</referenceAmount>
            <cashSettlement>true</cashSettlement>
        </amount>
    </trade>
</requestConfirmation>
let $input := $inXML/*[name() = name($inXML/*)]/* 
let $ns := "schema://fc.fasset/execution"
let $root := "executionReport"
let $keep := "id"
return 
element { fn:QName ($ns, $root)  }
        { hof:transform-ns-root-flatten($input, $ns, $keep) }
```

> Then I switch XSLT to transform `two-attr.xml`. Surprisingly, the XSLT transform is a success.

```
    <xsl:param name="ns" as="xs:string">schema://fc.fasset/product</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="attr" static="yes" as="xs:string*" select="'href', 'id'"/>
    =================================
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="local-name() = $attr">
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$ns}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

> The collective successful underlying transform is against the `one-attr.xml` model.  Java|ML API, Oxygen, XSLT returns the same result:

```
            <amount>
               <currency>
                  <id>settlementCurrency</id>USD</currency>
               <referenceAmount>StandardISDA</referenceAmount>
               <cashSettlement>true</cashSettlement>
            </amount>
```

Now here is the rub: it doesn’t look like a valid XML. For although I can get the `currency` text value

```
doc("/product/eqd/a7c1db2d.xml")//prod:trade//prod:amount/prod:currency/text()
```

, I expect below result to facilitate the search engine:

```
<executionReport xmlns="schema://fc.fasset/execution">
    <trade>
    <cal>
        <c>PRECEDING</c>
        <bcs>
            <id>businessCenters</id>
            <bc>USNY</bc>
            <bc>GBLO</bc>
        </bcs>
    </cal>
    <amount>
        <currency>USD</currency>        
        <id>settlementCurrency</id>
        <referenceAmount>StandardISDA</referenceAmount>
        <cashSettlement>true</cashSettlement>
    </amount>
    </trade>
</executionReport>
```

> Among the following solutions, the latest result is as below:

```
<executionReport xmlns="schema://fc.fasset/execution">
    <cal>
        <c>PRECEDING</c>
        <bcs>
            <bc>USNY</bc>
            <bc>GBLO</bc>
        </bcs>
<!-- Line9: id is out of <bcs> element and its context is completed lost!  -->
        <id>businessCenters</id>
    </cal>
    <amount>
        <currency>USD</currency>
<!-- Line14: id is in the correct position! -->
        <id>settlementCurrency</id>
        <referenceAmount>StandardISDA</referenceAmount>
        <cashSettlement>true</cashSettlement>
    </amount>
</executionReport>
```

> How can I get my XQuery and XSLT module work?

Comment: Please include more of the failing XQuery script.

Comment: Your XML might look unusual, but it is well-formed. The content of an element can contain text nodes and element nodes in any order. And it is of course searchable, though with a little difficulty. But as a matter of good practice, mixed content (text nodes as siblings of element nodes) is best reserved for textual markup, e.g. marking italic text within a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create attributes after you have started creating child nodes. So, if you are transforming the `@id` into `<id>` then you have to do that AFTER you have copied the other attributes.

The shortest and easiest way to avoid the problem is to sort the attributes, ensuring that the ones that will be copied forward are processed first, then the ones that will be converted to elements.

You could achieve that by sorting the sequence of items returned from the `hof:remove-attr-except()` function, ensuring that the sequence has attributes and then the elements:

```
element { fn:QName ($newNs, local-name($node)) }
  { for $item in (hof:remove-attr-except($node, $newNs, $keepAttr))
    order by $item instance of attribute() descending
    return $item }
```

You could also just have two separate FLWOR with a `where` clause that processes the `$keepAttr` and then those that will be converted into elements:

```
declare function hof:remove-attr-except
  ( $node as node()* ,
    $newNs as xs:string ,
    $keepAttr as xs:string* 
  ) as node()* 
  {
    for $attr in $node/@*
    where not(local-name($attr) = $keepAttr)
    return
      $node/@*[name() = $keepAttr], hof:transform-ns-root-flatten($node/node(), $newNs, $keepAttr)
    ,  
    for $attr in $node/@*
    where local-name($attr) = $keepAttr
    return 
     element {fn:QName ($newNs, name($attr))} {data($attr)}    
  };
```

But if you want those new elements to be outside of the original element, and you don't want to retain the attributes then I would change the processing of the element in your `typeswitch`, so that you call the function that converts those attributes into elements outside of the element constructor:

```
declare namespace hof = "http://fc.fasset/function";

declare function hof:attr-to-element
  ( $node as node()* ,
    $newNs as xs:string ,
    $keepAttr as xs:string* 
  ) as node()* 
  {  
    for $attr in $node/@*
    where local-name($attr) = $keepAttr
    return 
     element {fn:QName ($newNs, name($attr))} {data($attr)}    
  };  
  
declare function hof:transform-ns-root-flatten
  ( $nodes as node()* ,
    $newNs as xs:string ,
    $keepAttr as xs:string*
  ) as node()* 
  {
    for $node in $nodes
    return 
        typeswitch($node)
            case $node as element()
                return (element { fn:QName ($newNs, local-name($node)) }
                            { hof:transform-ns-root-flatten($node/node(), $newNs, $keepAttr)  }
                        ,
                        hof:attr-to-element($node, $newNs, $keepAttr)
                       )
            case $node as document-node()
                return hof:transform-ns-root-flatten($node/node(), $newNs, fn:normalize-space($keepAttr))          
    default return $node 
  };
```

The code above produces the following output from the provided input XML:

```
<executionReport xmlns="schema://fc.fasset/execution">
  <amount>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <id>settlementCurrency</id>
    <referenceAmount>StandardISDA</referenceAmount>
    <cashSettlement>true</cashSettlement>
  </amount>
</executionReport>
```

Comment: Note that while it's convenient to think of this in terms of order of execution ("You can't do X after doing Y") the formal definition is that in the sequence of items used to form the content of an element, attribute nodes must precede child nodes.

Comment: The first code example (sorting the results, but keeping your existing logic) simply avoids the error. If you don't like the output, and really want the elements moved outside of the currency element, then the last code block is what you would want. Though, your example doesn't show the other attributes retained in the output. Do you want them retained?

Comment: note that in my last example, the `hof:attr-to-element()` is invoked outside of the element constructor. It is the second item in the sequence of expressions for the `element()` case

Comment: In your 3rd block code, replace `{ hof:remove-attr-except($node, $newNs, $keepAttr) }` with `{ hof:remove-attr-except($node, $newNs, "") }`. You get `<currency>USD
</currency>
<referenceAmount>StandardISDA
</referenceAmount>`.  The form looks right but `id` attr is lost: It means `hof:attr-to-element` should precede `hof:remove-attr-except`. But Michael Kay's statement precipitates everything.

Comment: Look closer to my expected result : `USD` is back to `<currency>` and attr `id`( `<id>settlementCurrency</id>` ) becomes an element.  I don't want to retain ANY attr in the final XML but transform the $keepAttr to an element.  Can you try harder?

Comment: Okay, updated to produce the desired results. Instead of invoking `hof:remove-attr-except()` inside the element constructor, only invoke `hof:transform-ns-node-flatten()` and then outside of the element constructor, invoke `hof:attr-to-element()`. In general, I find that XSLT is much easier for transforming XML.

Comment: Thanks again!  Please see the edit. As it stands, my original module produces the desired  `<cal>` result and yours produces the desired `<amount>` result.   I don't understand! I feel sth like `for $e in $elements/node() return if ($e instance of element())  then ... else $e`  , in so doing `id` will not be moved out of the parent element??

Comment: So, I answered the question about *why* you were getting the error, and what it meant. I feel like this has now turned into a totally different question about how to transform your inputs into desired outputs. It might be better to ask that as a separate question, listing out the requirements for what you want to produce and rules for how to determine which `ID` belongs at which level. My answer would likely be an XSLT :)

Comment: Fair enough. My apology for wasting your time. And I thank you for sharing your knowledge with me!

Comment: I’m happy to help though. Don’t hesitate to post questions. Just keep them targeted.